# Count the number of existing values in a field in a record

Tags: java, mysql, sql, navicat

1. Such as I have a table of User---(id,name,age,hobby,sports)
2. Then it has a record that (1,"zhangsan",18,null,null);
3. Next you can see the total of record is 3, because hobby and sports are null.

use SQL sentences to count the number of existing values in a field in a record

Help and thanks

Comment: navicat mysql ,use sql to count what i have mentioned

Comment: data: tabel---User(id,name,age,hobby,sports)

Comment: User(1,"zhangsan",18,null,null), the result of count is 3

Comment: The data is relatively simple. Where are the tags you are referring to?

Comment: As you say it is very simple, so what are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: OK，the tagged is updated

Comment: You say simple but your request ambiguous.   Are you looking for the non-NULL columns which in your sample is 3 ?

Comment: If there are 20 fields in a record, and only the first 10 fields have data, how to count the number of field data through sql statement, this is what bothers me

Comment: I am not looking for a non-empty column with a sample of 3, but in a record, such as the User table above, there are 3 fields with data in it, then the count is 3, and I am confused about how to write it through the sql statement

Comment: can u write the sql Can you help to write the above sql statement about the User table, thank you

Comment: One option is to calculate the length of a string  len(concat( left(id,1),left(name,1),left(age,1),left(hobby,1),left(sports,1)))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions to count each column.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    -- repeat for all columns
    AS NumberOfNonNullColumns
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: it is amaing , i am trying

Comment: Perfect solution to my current problem as you have described and written, thanks a lot

Comment: To tell you the truth, I am relatively new, can you tell me where to receive the answer?